# derivative using chain rule within chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I'm trying to find the derivative of this without using any tricks, just chain rule, but I'm getting lost

$$\sin^3\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr)$$

well what confuses me is the power of 3 on the sin,
my assumption would be to put $-3\cos^2$ and then multiply it by the inside brackets derivative, but is it like a chain rule within a chain rule?

Comment: It is the custom on this site to format math with MathJax.  You've been here long enough to know that.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  To begin with, surround math expressions with`$` signs.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple applications of chain rule in a row.  Using Leibniz notation, $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dh}\frac{dh}{dx}$, or using Lagrange notation, letting $F(x)=f(g(h(x)))$ you have $F'(x)=f'(g(h(x)))g'(h(x))h'(x)$.  This of course generalizes to any number of compositions of functions.

Comment: ahh I understand now, it was the application of chain rule 4 times basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes chains inside chains.

One way to think about it is to just keep pushing out one more nested function and differentiating, working it like so.

$\frac {d}{dx} \sin^3\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2}\\
(3\sin^2\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2})\frac {d}{dx}\sin\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2}\\
(3\sin^2\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2})(\cos\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2})\frac {d}{dx}\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2}\\
(3\sin^2\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2})(\cos\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2})(\frac {1}{2\sqrt{x^3+2x^2}})\frac {d}{dx}(x^3 + 2x^2)\\
(3\sin^2\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2})(\cos\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2})(\frac {1}{2\sqrt{x^3+2x^2}})(3x^2 + 4x)$

The other is to think of the composition of functions beforehand.

$u = x^3 + 2x^2\\
v = \sqrt u\\
w = \sin v\\
y = w^3$

And then apply the chain rule:

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {dy}{dw}\frac {dw}{dv}\frac {dv}{du}\frac {du}{dx}\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = (3w^2)(\cos v)(\frac {1}{2\sqrt{u}})(3x^2 + 4x)\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = (3\sin^2 \sqrt{x^3+2x^2})(\cos \sqrt{x^3+2x^2})(\frac {1}{2\sqrt{x^3+2x^2}})(3x^2 + 4x)\\$

I would say the second approach is conceptually more difficult, but easier to keep organized.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=f(x),\text{then},(u^n)'=nu'u^{n-1}$

$(\cos u)'=u'(-\sin u)$

$(\sqrt u)'=\dfrac{u'}{2\sqrt u}$

$y=\sin^3 (\cos(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}))$

$y'=3 (\cos(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}))'    \cos (\cos(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2})) \sin^2 (\cos(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}))= 3  (\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2})'    (-\sin(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}))    \cos (\cos(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2})) \sin^2 (\cos(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}))=   3\times  \dfrac{(3x^2+4x)}{2\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2} } \times  (-\sin(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}))   \times \cos (\cos(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}))\times \sin^2 (\cos(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2})) $

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(x) = \cos(\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}})$. Then, your function reads $\sin^{3}(u(x))$. By the chain rule:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{3}(u(x)) = 3\sin^{2}(u(x))\cos(u(x))\frac{d}{dx}u(x) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
Analogously:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx}u(x) = -\sin(\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}})\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}} \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
and, finally:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}}}\frac{d}{dx}(x^{3}+2x^{2}) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}}}(3x^{2}+4x)\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}
Putting (\ref{1}), (\ref{2}) and (\ref{3}) together, we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{3}(\cos(\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}}))= \frac{-(9x^{2}+12x)\sin^{2}(\cos(\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}}))\cos(\cos(\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}}))\sin(\cos(\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}}))}{\sqrt{x^{3}+2x^{2}}}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

This is Leibniz'notation  is useful, albeit heavy:
\begin{alignat}{2}
\quad&\frac{\mathrm d\Bigl(\sin^3\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr) \Bigr)}{\mathrm d x}=&& \\
 &\qquad\frac{\mathrm d\Bigl(\sin^3\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr) \Bigr)}{\mathrm d\Bigl(\sin\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr) \Bigr)}&\times\frac{\mathrm d\Bigl(\sin\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr) \Bigr)}{\mathrm d\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr)}&\times
\frac{\mathrm d\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr)}{\mathrm d\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)}\\
&&\times\frac{\mathrm d\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)}{\mathrm d\bigl(x^3 +2x^2\bigr)}&\times \frac{\mathrm d(x^3+2x^2)}{\mathrm dx} 
\end{alignat}
\begin{align}
\text{i.e. }\qquad3\sin^2\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr) \times  \cos\bigl(\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr)\bigr)&\times\bigl(-\sin\bigl(\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}\bigr) \\
{}\times \frac 1{2\sqrt{x^3 +2x^2}}&\times (3x^2+4x).
\end{align}